# Particle acquiring mass as it moves upward

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum

A particle whose initial mass is $m_0$ is projected vertically upwards at time $t=0$ with speed $gT$, where $T$ is a constant and $g$ is the uniform gravitational acceleration. At time $t$, the mass of the particle has increased to $m_0e^{t/T}$. If the added mass is at rest relative to particle when it is acquired, find the time when it is at highest point and mass at that instant.

My attempt:

I applied the impulse momentum equation considering that at a general time $t$, the mass is $m_0e^{t/T}$ and it is moving upwards with speed $v$; after a time $dt$, mass $dm$ (moving with speed $v$) adds to it and then they both move with a speed $v+dv$ Therfore,
$$(m_0e^{t/T}+dm)(v+dv)-(m_0e^{t/T}+dm)v=-m_0e^{t/T}gdt$$
After simplifying we get
$$gdt=-dv$$
On integrating with proper limits we get $t=T$, however the answer given is $T\ln(2)$ although my approach seems correct. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe either the question is incorrectly worded, or the expected answer is wrong.

Your reasoning is correct, although it doesn't really take any math to arrive at your answer: if the added mass is indeed at rest relative to the particle as it moves, the added mass imparts no impulse on the particle: the particle and the added mass are already moving with the same velocity. The mass increases, however the gravitational acceleration does not depend on the mass, so the particle maintains its acceleration as it moves upward, reaching the peak at time $t=gT/g=T$.

I think the intention was to ask what happens when the added mass it at rest with respect to the "world frame", i.e. the frame with respect to which the particle is initially moving with a velocity of $gT$. Then, the added mass actually decelerates the particle. The answer does turn out to be $T\ln 2$ in this case.

I'll leave it to you to attempt the problem as stated this way, let me if you have further issues.

Comment: Yes i considered the situation as you said and im getting the answer now

Comment: Looks like the author made a mistake in the question.Thank You for your answer!